# Using class_exists with namespaces on PHP 5.2

Tags: php, composer-php

I don't have PHP 5.2 installed to test on.

I want to use `if (class_exists('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader'))` to test whether [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is installed, however my code needs to be compatible with PHP 5.2.

Will PHP 5.2 get stuck on the backslash characters? Or will it just return false and continue on with the script?

Comment: Out of interest, what's the reason you need to support 5.2 these days? it went End Of Life nearly two years ago, and hasn't had any security patches since then. No sane network administrator would allow it anywhere near their systems.

Comment: Hah, I totally agree. I'm just submitting a small patch to an open source project and trying not to break anything. I'm pushing to get them to drop 5.2 support though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces don't exist in PHP 5.2 -- they were added as a new feature in PHP 5.3.

So the direct answer to your question is yes, PHP 5.2 will get stuck on the backslashes, because as far as it's concerned, it's not valid syntax.

The line of code you quoted is not in itself syntactically invalid, since as you point out, it's just a string. Passing it into `class_exists()` may or may not break things though -- I also don't have a copy of PHP 5.2 handy any more to confirm. If I were to guess, I would expect it to throw some kind of warning or notice rather than blowing up completely.

But composer itself won't work with 5.2, so if the user is on 5.2 then by definition they can't have Composer installed. I would suggest therefore that you could avoid the whole issue by checking the PHP version directly first, by calling [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) and [`version_compare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php). This will allow you to avoid any unpleasantness with the `class_exists()` call.

Comment: It's just a string though. Will it actually throw an error, or will it return false and let me get on with things?

Comment: Ah, nice idea checking for 5.3 before even calling class_exists. In this case I just ended up testing for `ComposerAutoloaderInit` instead to sidestep the whole issue, but I'd still be interested to try this on 5.2 and see what happens.